# Shortcut to quickly add texture in the shader editor doesn't work?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shortcut

I am trying to add textures in the *Shader Editor* using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but nothing happens.

When I first came across this shortcut watching a tutorial, it worked perfectly fine but the next day I opened the same project it didn't work anymore. And since then, still doesn't work.

I have updated Blender to 2.91.2 in order to see if that would fix the problem but nothing changed.

Would you know what's the problem or where I could find that shortcut in the preferences in order to see what's wrong or just add the shortcut if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Did you accidentally disable the "Node Wrangler" add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the *Node Wrangler* add-on enabled.

[image]